# CSS trick: get property value into another css tag

Tags: html, css

I trying to tune up an internal site only with CSS (company policy: it's short of working, so server will not be touch, indeed it will be done with a CSS extension)

And we need to include a value existing in a property in the HTML into the view (seen by user)

HTML looks like:

```
<div class="card card-employe" employid="a453">
    <a href=... target="_blank">
        ...
    </a>
</div>
```

so with a CSS selector I can insert text on the cards with:

```
.card-employe::before {
  content: "_ #EmployeID:";
}
```

but I dream for something like more advance like

```
.card-employe::before {
  content: "#EmployeID:" + this.employid;
}
```

so the text will show:

```
#EmployeID:a453
```

is that possible with just CSS ??

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is possible, use this:

```
.card-employe::before {
  content: "#EmployeID:" attr(employid);
}
```

for more info about `attr`, visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr

Comment: in css, the space is used as concatenation operator in place of +

Comment: i hope it helped :)

Comment: @pGrnd2 remember that this text generated by css will not be selectable by the user

Comment: not selectable : yap, that's nothing can be done, we will have to live with that until touching the server